# I need to create a report to view all users in all of the SP (O365) permissions groups for a site

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions

In one of our O365 SharePoint sites, we have a ton of different permissions groups with various people in each one. Is it possible to generate a report that lists each of these permissions groups and who is in each one?

I have searched for the answer, but I have been unable to find it. I thought it would be something that is readily available as something many would need, bit I can't find it.

Can anyone help me out with a PowerShell script or a way to do this online?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the PowerShell script in SharePoint Online Management Shell to get a CSV report for SharePoint site collection groups and members. Please change the relevant information for your own environment.

```
Function Get-SiteGroup-Members 
{ 
    param ($sSiteUrl,$sUserName,$sPassword,$FileName) 
    try 
    {    
        #SPO Client Object Model Context 
        $spoCtx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($sSiteUrl) 
        $spoCredentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($sUserName, $sPassword)   
        #$spoCredentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($sUserName, $sPassword)    # for on premise
        $spoCtx.Credentials = $spoCredentials        

        $web = $spoCtx.Web
        $spGroups =$web.SiteGroups

        $spoCtx.Load($web)
        $spoCtx.Load($spGroups)
        $spoCtx.ExecuteQuery() 

        Write-Host "Groups Count= $($spGroups.Count)"

        foreach($spGroup in $spGroups)
        { 
            $site =@()
            $users = $spGroup.Users
            $spoCtx.Load($spGroup)
            $spoCtx.Load($users)
            $spoCtx.ExecuteQuery()

            foreach($spUser in $users)
            { 
                try
                {
                    $spoCtx.Load($spUser)
                    $spoCtx.ExecuteQuery()

                    $site += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
                                    SiteUrl =$sSiteUrl
                                    GroupName = $spGroup.Title
                                    PrincipalType= $spGroup.PrincipalType
                                    User =$spUser.LoginName
                                    UserEmail =$spUser.Email
                                    } | Select  SiteUrl,GroupName,PrincipalType,User,UserEmail


                }
                catch [System.Exception] 
                { 
                    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red $_.Exception.ToString()    
                }    


            } 

            $site| Export-CSV ("C:\"+$FileName+".csv") -NoTypeInformation -Append #-Encoding UTF8          

        }       

        Read-Host -Prompt "file created Successfull..! Press any key to close this window"

    } 
    catch [System.Exception] 
    { 
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red $_.Exception.ToString()    
        Read-Host -Prompt "Operation failed..! Press any key to close this and re run the script"
    }     
} 


$FileName= "ReportName"          
$sSiteUrl = "https://domain.sharepoint.com"  
$sUserName = "user@domain.onmicrosoft.com" 
$sPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "YourPassword" -AsPlainText -Force 


Write-Host "Getting Site Collection group Members"
Write-Host "-----------------------------------" 
Get-SiteGroup-Members -sSiteUrl $sSiteUrl -sUserName $sUserName -sPassword $sPassword  -FileName $FileName
```

Comment: Thanks for the script. When I run it, having plugged in our info, I get this:

PS C:\> Get-O365GrpMembers2
Getting Site Collection group Members
-----------------------------------
System.Management.Automation.PSArgumentException: Cannot find type [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded.
   at System.Management.Automation.MshCommandRuntime.ThrowTerminatingError(ErrorRecord errorRecord)
Operation failed..! Press any key to close this and re run the script:

Comment: Looking more closely at your script, it looks like it's designed to list O365 groups and their members (along with other info about each member), though I will admit I don't understand all of it. I am looking for a way to list all of the SP permissions groups and their members, not O365 groups. Does that make sense?